# Homomorphisms and order

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am studying through my algebraic structures textbook and I came across the theorem that if $\alpha: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism of groups and Order(g) = n then 
Order($\alpha(g) $) divides Order(g). The proof goes as follows.

Since $g^n=1$ then $\alpha(g)^n = (\alpha(g)^n))=(\alpha(1))=1_H$ so that 
Order($\alpha(g) $) divides Order(g). I know that in a group G if the order of an element $g \in G$ is n then if $g^k=1$ implies $n|k$ but why is this necessarily true for ($\alpha(g) $) since it is an element of H?? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the notation is confusing you. Write $h = \alpha(g)$. You have established that $h^n = 1_H$. Therefore the order of $h$ divides $n$. But $n$ is the order of $g$, so you're done.

Comment: Thank you now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

The thinking goes like this:

We know by the properties of the homomorphism which you outline above that $(\alpha(g))^n=\alpha(g^n)=1$, and although this $n$ may not be the order of this element, as it could hit zero before $n$, we do know this value for which it hits zero is a divisor of $n$. The only property used in the new group $H$ is that you know that $n$ brings $\alpha(g)\in H$ to the identity. The same reasoning for proving the same thing in $G$ applies.